Problem displaying datagrid based on a list with FluentUI
Im trying to display a datagrid based on a model I have.
Ive been looking on google but the datagrids seem to be with zero styling which makes it hard to believe.
Is that indeed the case?
Isnt there some sort of basic datagrid I can display based on model just like with any other library?
If so, How do I do that?
Because I cant find anywhere a good example for that.
Even a link for a proper tutorial will be great. ( focus on displaying it based on a list of class I fill with a query from db ).

There is a lot of datagrid library for the blazor, a lot of them support the CSS style. You need provide the codes or library you have used and which error you have faced, then we could provide the solution for you.

This sounds like a rant about the lack of documentation and examples for the FluentUI grid.  Here is not an appropriate place for that, and the question will probably be closed for that reason - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.  "Isnt there some sort of basic datagrid I can display based on model just like with any other library?"  [Polite] You can't have looked far, there are lots.  Just search "Blazor Data Grid"  For example, you can Css format QuickGrid any which way you want.
